# Can't get all titles from a list with Python WebScraping

Tags: python, selenium

I'm practicing web scraping with Python atm and I found a problem, I wanted to scrape one website that has a list of anime that I watched before but when I try to scrape it (via requests or selenium) it only gets around 30 of 110 anime names from the page.
Here is my code with selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://anilist.co/user/Agusmaris/animelist/Completed")
data = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
for title in data.find_all(class_="title"):
    print(title.getText())
```

And when I run it, the page source only shows up until an anime called 'Golden time' when there are like 70 or more left that are in the page.

Thanks

Edit: Code that works now thanks to 'supputuri':

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://anilist.co/user/Agusmaris/animelist/Completed")
time.sleep(3)
footer = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.footer")
preY = 0
print(str(footer))
while footer.rect['y'] != preY:
    preY = footer.rect['y']
    footer.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    print('loading')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for title in soup.find_all(class_="title"):
    print(title.getText())
driver.close()
driver.quit()
ret = input()
```

Comment: It's probably an issue with timing, make sure you get the code after everything has been loaded and rendered.
There is also another way, you can query the JSON API https://anilist.co/graphql instead of the whole website.

Comment: @Mr.bug I think it is a spam website, see my answer below

Comment: im not spamming lol, im just trying to figure out how could i export some anime names from that page. Why would i spam it on the first place?

Comment: Sorry, not accusing you directly, but there is something suspicious to me about that website.

Comment: Your code attempts to get all the rows?

Comment: My bad, I modified the code to make it show the titles but its still showing up until 'Golden Time' when it should go up to 'Youkoso Jitsuryoku Shijou Shugi no Kyoushitsu e '. PD: I Edited the title, what im looking for it´s not rows, it´s the titles

Comment: Can you pause the script and scroll the page all the way to the last anime  and then run the script to see if you can get all the titles. Just wanted to make sure the anime are not loading dynamically when user scroll down. If that's the case, selenium can get the data which is available in the current page.

Comment: How could I do it? sorry Im newbie on this things

Comment: Yes, my guess is correct. The anime are loading dynamically, so you don't see all the anime when you get the page source.

Comment: Then how can i do to get all anime in the page source? i dont know how to pause the script while the page is loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.
Make sure to add `import time`

```
driver.get("https://anilist.co/user/Agusmaris/animelist/Completed")
time.sleep(3)
footer =driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.footer")
preY =0
while footer.rect['y']!=preY:
    preY = footer.rect['y']
    footer.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    time.sleep(1)
print(str(driver.page_source))
```

This will iterate until all the anime is loaded and then gets the page source.
Let us know if this was helpful.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Sorry if it's too much to ask, but is there a way to scrap this page only with requests module? So it doesnt have to open the browser and all that stuff

Comment: I will take a look using requests module, might be tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the jist of what I get when I load the page source:

AniListwindow.al_token = 'E1lPa1kzYco5hbdwT3GAMg3OG0rj47Gy5kF0PUmH';Sorry, AniList requires Javascript.
Please enable Javascript or http://outdatedbrowser.com>upgrade to a modern web browser.Sorry, AniList requires a modern browser.
Please http://outdatedbrowser.com>upgrade to a newer web browser.

Since I know damn well that Javascript is enabled and my Chrome version is fully up to date, and the URL listed takes one to a nonsecure website to "download" a new version of your browser, I think this is a spam site.  Not sure if you were aware of that when posting so I won't flag as such, but I wanted you and others who come across this to be aware.

Comment: I get the same when i run it with requests module, and no, its not spam...

Comment: Well in any case, that's what the page source is, so I don't think you'll be able to get any more than that.